# No module named 'pyexpat' error when embedding Python in C++

Tags: python, c++

I linked Python 3.8.7 dynamically to a Visual Studio C++ console application *TestPython.exe* with the following code to try *plistlib* library (which is necessary in my real application):

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Python.h"

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Write name:   ";
    std::cin >> name;

    std::cout << "name: " << name << "\n";

    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject* moduleMainString = PyUnicode_FromString("__main__");
    PyObject* moduleMain = PyImport_Import(moduleMainString);

    PyRun_SimpleString(
        "import plistlib\n"\
        "def testDict(a):\n"
        "   pl = dict(aString = a)\n"\
    );

    PyObject* func = PyObject_GetAttrString(moduleMain, "testDict");
    PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(1, PyUnicode_FromString(name.c_str()));
    PyObject* result = PyObject_CallObject(func, args);

    Py_Finalize();

    system("pause");
}
```

In my developer computer (where I have Python installed) the executable works well. When I run it in a different computer with no Python installed, the application shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
   File "plistlib.py", line 65, in <module>
   File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
   File "xml\parser\expat.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyexpat'
```

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKKbq.png)

When I run it in a different computer I took care of including in the same directory:

- Application *TestPython.exe*.
- *python38.dll* and *python38.zip* which are found in https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ Python 3.8.7 Windows embeddable package (64-bit).

The Python files bundled with *TestPython.exe* properly match the Python version of the developer computer (this was typically the solution in related 'pyexpat' questions, but not for this one).

Comment: thx for not posting only the image of the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: place ALL files found in the Python 3.8.7 Windows embeddable package in the same directory (not just the .dll and .zip). In particular, there is file *pyexpat.pyd* which was missing.