# I can't install tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

When I'm installing tkinter by using "pip install tkinter"
there is an error saying "No module named 'pyexpat'"
what should I do?

edit: for information i have downloading the tkinter but it doesn't work on my vscode. I was a Newbie btw

Comment: `tkinter` should be installed by default. What is the exact issue. Have you tried using tkinter before. You shouldn't need to `pip install`

Comment: You can't use pip to install tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

The Tkinter module is part of the general installation of python3 and as the docs says you can install it like this:

> The tkinter package (“Tk interface”) is the standard Python interface to the Tcl/Tk GUI toolkit. Both Tk and tkinter are available on most Unix platforms, including macOS, as well as on Windows systems.
>
> Running python -m tkinter from the command line should open a window
> demonstrating a simple Tk interface, letting you know that tkinter is
> properly installed on your system, and also showing what version of
> Tcl/Tk is installed, so you can read the Tcl/Tk documentation specific
> to that version.
>
> Tkinter supports a range of Tcl/Tk versions, built either with or
> without thread support. The official Python binary release bundles
> Tcl/Tk 8.6 threaded. See the source code for the _tkinter module for
> more information about supported versions

Tkinter also has its own documentation, in which they explain how to install the module in different OSs. You can access the docs [here](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html).

Also I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66390503/no-module-named-pyexpat-error-when-embedding-python-in-c) concerning to the pyexpat module that could be useful for you if following the tkinter module documentation doesn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Btw thank you for Answering the question :)